# GitHub: Permission denied (publickey). Unable to push to server

Tags: git, github

I am getting the error:

```
VehicleXray git:(master) ✗ git push live master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

The command "git remote -v" shows:

```
live    ssh://root@vehiclexray.com/var/repo/VehicleXray.git (fetch)
live    ssh://root@vehiclexray.com/var/repo/VehicleXray.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/enayet123/VehicleXray.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/enayet123/VehicleXray.git (push)
```

I am clearly new to GitHub and minimal understanding on how to use it. I have already attempted to create a SSH key with the private key stored locally on my laptop and the public keys given to both my server and GitHub. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing with Github. You're having ssh troubles pushing to `ssh://root@vehiclexray.com/`. The solution is the same as with GH: copy your public key to `root@vehiclexray.com`:

```
ssh-copy-id root@vehiclexray.com
```

Comment: YES! I love you. I don't know why but it wouldnt work when I manually copied over the SSH key?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have problem with your public key on server. Try to login using ssh:

```
ssh -vvv root@vehiclexray.com
```

`-vvv` option prints debug messages

Your public key should be in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. Also public key authentication must be enabled in `sshd_config` file: `PubkeyAuthentication yes`. After making changes into this file, you must restart ssh.

Also choosing `root` as user may be not the best idea. Logging as root can be disabled at sshd level. You should create unprivileged user to access git repository.

Another thing: it is only possible to push into bare repository. You can clone bare repository with `git clone --bare <repository>` command.

More information: [Git on the Server - Setting Up the Server](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server)

Comment: Authenticates successfully

Answer (score 0):

check out git hubs help https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote#what-can-i-push-to

try this

1. git remote rm origin
2. git remote add origin
3. git@github.com:user/repo.git git push origin master

Comment: My issue isn't with pushing to GitHub itself. I'm trying to push to my server of which has the remote called "live"

Comment: Have you tried looking at this?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728054/git-push-to-live-server

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Step 1 - `git remote rm origin`
Step 2 - [select the http option in github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqWnr.png)
step 3 - run the following command again

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/yourdirectory/link.git  
git branch -M main  
git push -u origin main
```