# Managing a Django application/project as it grows ( in terms of changes in models, increase in features )

Tags: django, version-control, django-models

I need your advice on managing a Django application as it grows in terms of features and models.

For instance as a application grows, we often need to add in new features.

Adding new features involves adding new models, or adding a new field within a model.

How would you go about doing that without closing the web application ( which runs on 
DJango)

How would you integrate versioning tools such as GIT in managing your DJango project/app?
Best.

Comment: Could you try to clarify what "How would you go about doing that without closing the web application" means?

Comment: oh, by "without closing the web application" means without shutting it offline; allowing the web application to work ( as in having read capability) while I am upgrading the application.

Answer (score 4):

A comprehensive answer would be too long and very subjective. I will instead try to point you in the direction of some very handy tools that will help you answer some of the points raised in your question.

1. [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) for adding new models and dealing with changes to existing models. South is a very handy migration tool.
2. [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.1/) and/or [Buildout](http://www.buildout.org/) for deploying your application, changes and all.
3. [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) for letting you get away without reinventing the wheel as well as for new ideas on how to tackle your problems. Pinax is a collection of (mostly) pluggable Django applications that solve common problems.

Various Django developers have written on the subject of integrating `git` etc. A Google search should help you find the popular ones. For e.g. here is one about deploying Django applications [written by Jacob Kaplan-Moss](http://jacobian.org/writing/django-apps-with-buildout/), one of the founders of Django.

Here are some things that I learned from my experience. They are not all Django specific.

1. Clearly define sanity checks when you are about to migrate data/schema. Verify them post migration.
2. Keep a project diary. Log all "events" such as migrations, version changes etc.
3. Keep an eye on [Django Snippets](http://djangosnippets.org/). Quite handy.

Answer (score 0):

**the idea** of the framework is really to structure your application, so the application should grow in a sane way if you follow the Model/View/Template structure.

What is great about django is that each functionnality should be contained by an application. If you need a new functionnality, you create a new application and thus a new model. Things stay separated and clear.

Concerning `git` you should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875698/developing-django-projects-using-git).

Comment: hmm i see. but what if i want to add a new field in an existing model? how do i do that?

Comment: @DjangoRocks: use a migration tool to add a field to an existing model. For example see: http://south.aeracode.org/docs/tutorial/part1.html#changing-the-model

Comment: if you don't want to use another tool (my case): to add a field: add it with the null=True, blank=True and run sync db. to remove a field: remove it from the model, remove it from the db with an alter table and run syncdb.

Comment: interesting solution. What do you do when you encounter fields that cannot be `null` or `blank`?